# 6+12 PIN (Macbook Air 2011 - A1370) SSD transfer speeds issues

Tags: hard-drive, usb, ssd, hardware, sata

I upgraded my MacBook Air 2011 (A1370) to a Crucial MX500 SATA SSD with better speeds and would like to give the original APPLE TS128C (128gb) a second life.

I have tried a basic enclosure that does the Apple 6+12 PIN => USB 2/3 conversion but the read speed doesn't go above 50 mb /s.

I figure there are 2 ways to looking at this:

- Either find and use a better USB3 case that does the Apple 6+12 PIN => USB 2/3 conversion with a better chipset, in which case I need recommendations?
- use a Apple 6+12 PIN => SATA 3 conversion board and then use a classic SATA 3 to USB 3 enclosure but I don't know if that will work?

So what do I need to look out for to get good transfer speeds?

Comment: Added information about my current issue : very slow transfer speeds with a basic enclosure.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! I'm personally voting for this to be reopened as it's primarily a technical question rather than a use-case-specific recommendation. If you need more specific recommendation-oriented advice, the Hardware Recs SO is also a good place to look.

Comment: @JMY1000 Thank you... please re-open...

Comment: Have a look at: https://eshop.macsales.com/item/OWC/MAU3ENVOY11/